# How do you truncate mysql table using php script

Tags: php, mysql, truncate

I have been working with a php script that the user can upload a csv file to a mysql database. I can connect and get a uploaded successfuly message but when I browse the contents of the table there is nothing, so I decided to test the very first step in the script to see if I can first truncate existing data. however, this is not working either, so I suspect I'm doing something wrong from the get go. Below is the following scripts I'm using to do this. Why is this not working?

CONNECT SCRIPT(connect.php)

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "plfwinv";
$password = "mypassword";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

TRUNCATE SCRIPT(upload.php - The script I load)

```
<?php

include "connect.php"; //Connect to Database

$deleterecords = "TRUNCATE TABLE plfwinvtable"; //empty the table of its current records
mysqli_query( $conn, $deleterecords );

?>
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: You are mixing **`_mysql`** with **`_mysqli`** ....

Comment: This has come up before how do I correct this?

Comment: Would I use mysqli_query

Comment: Ok I changed mysql_query($deleterecords) to mysqli_query($deleterecords) but this did not solve the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you forgot to select database

For Access denied issue, Grant privileges to user on that database.

```
Grant ALL
On <database>.*
TO <user>;
```

Comment: Ok So I updated the connect script to...
 <?php
 $servername = "localhost";
 $username = "plfwinv";
 $password = "plfwInv4321";
 $db = "plfwinventory";
 
 // Create connection
 $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);

 // Check connection
 if ($conn->connect_error) {
 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 } 
 echo "Connected successfully";
 ?>
Now  i get the message... Connection failed: Access denied for user 'plfwinv'@'localhost' to database 'plfwinventory' -might local host be the issue?

Comment: Grant privilege to user on that database: Grant all on <database>.* to user;

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response Palo. So I updated the code in my question, as well, I tested it but the data still does not truncate.

NOTE: Apparently I got locked out from posting comments because I updated the question after you gave an answer and is why I am posting this question as an answer.